# Inference of underscore types

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, shapeless

*[ I was unable to explain the problem with less verbosity. The core of the issue is that the compiler infers an underscore (`_`) type. In particular, `[_ >: SomeType <: SomeOtherType]`. I am clueless about when, how and why that is possible ]*

As a scala exercise, I am trying to encode a vector of elements with a given size.
As a necessary step, I started by copying an existing encoding of natural numbers:

```
sealed trait Natural extends Product with Serializable {
  def +(that: Natural): Natural
}

case object Zero extends Natural {
  override def +(that: Natural): Natural = that
}

final case class Suc[N <: Natural](n: N) extends Natural {
  override def +(that: Natural): Natural = Suc(n + that)
}
```

I believe the following diagram is a faithful portrayal of the type relation:
[image]
I then attempted to model a vector parameterized by a type on the elements and another type on size. To explain the problem though, I assumed a vector of ints and parameterized only the size of the vector :

```
import shapeless.=:!=  

sealed trait Vector[+Size <: Natural] extends Product with Serializable {
  def head: Int
  def tail: Vector[Natural]

  def plus[OtherSize >: Size <: Natural]
  (that: Vector[OtherSize])
  (implicit ev: OtherSize =:!= Natural): Vector[OtherSize]
}

case object VectorNil extends Vector[Zero.type] {
  override def head: Nothing = throw new Exception("Boom!")
  override def tail: Vector[Zero.type] = throw new Exception("Boom")

  override def plus[OtherSize >: Zero.type <: Natural]
  (that: Vector[OtherSize])
    (implicit ev: =:!=[OtherSize, Natural]): Vector[OtherSize] = this

}

final case class VectorCons[N <: Natural](
  head: Int,
  tail: Vector[N]
) extends Vector[Suc[N]] {

  override def plus[OtherSize >: Suc[N] <: Natural]
  (that: Vector[OtherSize])
    (implicit ev: =:!=[OtherSize, Natural]): Vector[OtherSize] = that
}
```

Notice that `VectorCons[N]` is actually a Vector of size `Suc[N]`. (extends `Vector[Suc[N]]`).
Method `plus` should add the elements of two vectors of **the same size**. I wanted to raise to the type level the verification that you can only sum vectors of the same size.
Notice that the conjunction of the type bounds `OtherSize >: Size <: Natural` with the implicit evidence should achieve that (see similar example at the bottom), but:

```
val foo = VectorCons(1, VectorCons(2, VectorNil))
//type -> VectorCons[Suc[Zero.type]]
// note that foo is (can be viewed) as Vector[Suc[Suc[Zero.type]], i.e
// a vector of 2 elements

val bar = VectorCons(3, VectorNil)
//type -> VectorCons[Zero.type]

val baz = foo.plus(bar)
//type -> Vector[Suc[_ >: Suc[Zero.type] with Zero.type <: Natural]]  !! How is this possible ?? !!
```

to my frustration, `baz` compiles just fine!! The shapeless type constrain doesn't work; well, because `OtherSize` really is different from `Natural`; particularly, it is `Suc[_ >: Suc[Zero.type] with Zero.type <: Natural]`.
So, I am very much confused with the type of `baz`! This is what allows the constraint to be bypassed.

1. What did the compiler infer for the type of `baz`/`bar`?
2. Is that an existential type ?
3. Is the compiler allowed to infer such things?
4. Is that not undesirable behavior ?

At this point, I am not concerned whether or not this is the correct encoding for a vector. Just wanted to understand how can the compiler infer that type for `baz` ?

**p.s**
1 - I am aware the return `that` on the implementation of method `plus` on VectorCons does not achieve what the `plus` semantics implies, but that is not important for the question.

**###### Extra #######**
I suspect this weird (at least for me) behavior has something to to with  the natural numbers. The following code works fine!! :
[Disregard the absurd semantics of the code]

```
  sealed trait Animal extends Product with Serializable
  case class Dog() extends Animal
  case class Cow() extends Animal
  case object NoBox extends Animal //Not important
```

and,

```
trait Vector[+A <: Animal] {
  def head: A

  def plus[That >: A <: Animal]
  (that: Vector[That])
    (implicit ev: =:!=[That, Animal]): Vector[That]
}

case object Nil extends Vector[NoBox.type] {
  def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException("Boom!")

  override def plus[That >: NoBox.type <: Animal]
  (that: Vector[That])(implicit ev: =:!=[That, Animal]): Vector[That] = this
}

case class Cons[A <: Animal](head: A) extends Vector[A] {

  override def plus[That >: A <: Animal]
  (that: Vector[That])(implicit ev: =:!=[That, Animal]): Vector[That] = that
}
```

whereby:

```
val foo = Cons(Dog())
val bar = Cons(Cow())

// Compiles
val baz = foo.plus(foo)
val baz2 = bar.plus(bar)

// Does not compile  (what I would expect)  
val baz3 = bar.plus(foo)
val baz4 = foo.plus(bar)
```

Thank you for your input,

Comment: Is there some documentation for types like `=:!=` ? I don't seem to find any.

Comment: I have two similar pieces of code you might want to look into: [this](https://github.com/MarkusA380/Euclid/tree/master/euclid/src) and [this](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/NwnebIK/0). One doesn't use Shapeless except for `Lazy`, while the other is more concise and performant.

Comment: @MarkusAppel I don't know the documentation for the `=:!=` in particular. But, give a look at https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html#fn:16 . If you read with care, you will be able to understand the `=:!=` easily.

Comment: This does seem weird. But 1) why do you want `Vector` to be covariant? 2) why not just `def plus(that: Vector[Size])`?

Comment: Not an answer, but having `tail` typed as `Vector[Natural]` seems like the root of your problems here (the covariance requirement, etc.). It's a useless type—you're best off changing it.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov 2) Because `Vector` is covariant on `Size` you cannot do `plus(that: Vector[Size]`). We would get the compile error: `covariant type Size occurs in contravariant position in type Vector[Size]` . 1) Because otherwise I would not be able to have `tail: Vector[N]` on the `VectorCons[N <: Natural]` since then `Vector[N]` would not be a subtype of `Vector[Natural]` even though `N <: Natural`. 
Most likely @Travis is correct, but still curious on the actual explanation for the behavior.

Comment: To fix the problem in 1), you could change `tail` in  to `def tail: Vector[_ <: Natural]` or add a type member `type TailSize <: Natural; def tail[Vector[TailSize]`.